# Fabric.js with IText

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to download fabric.js, I'm doing it through this page

http://fabricjs.com/build/

But whatever the options I select, the result doesn't include iText. For example, with all the options selected:

http://fabricjs.com/build/files/text,cufon,gestures,easing,parser,freedrawing,interaction,serialization,image_filters,gradient,pattern,shadow,node.js

How can I get fabric.js with iText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the latest build from [github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tags) or use CDN http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js